# Workaround for specialized template for member function, when template class is not specialized

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I'm building a datastructure class with an std-like interface, and implementing different iterators for the data structure.

Conceptually, what I would like to do is something like this:

```
template <class DataT>
class DataStructure
{
protected:
    DataT& Data;
public:
    DataStructure(DataT& data) : Data(data) {}
    class BaseIterator
    {
    public:
        BaseIterator()
        {
            cout<<"BaseIterator"<<endl;
        }
    };

    class DerrivedIterator1 : public BaseIterator
    {
    public:
        DerrivedIterator1()
        {
            cout<<"DerrivedIterator1"<<endl;
        }
    };

    class DerrivedIterator2 : public BaseIterator
    {
    public:
        DerrivedIterator2()
        {
            cout<<"DerrivedIterator2"<<endl;
        }
    };

    template<class IterT>
    IterT Begin()
    {
        //none-specialized implementation. Possibly throw exception
    }

    template<>
    DerrivedIterator1 Begin<DerrivedIterator1>()
    {
        //Find beginning for DerrivedIterator1
    }

    template<>
    DerrivedIterator2 Begin<DerrivedIterator2>()
    {
        //Find beginning for DerrivedIterator1
    }
};
```

But this of course does not compile since C++ doesn't allow to specialize template member functions in none-specialized template containers.

The obvious workaround is of course to declare 2 different functions: Begin_Iterator1 and Begin_Iterator2 and be done with it. But I'm looking for a workaround that doesn't change the interface.

Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot to mention that this is for a HW assignment and so boost and even std is not an option.

Comment: `template<IterT> IterT Begin<IterT>()` will also not compile because there is no function `Begin` to even specialize. Also, functions can't be partially specialized at all.

Comment: Ad edit: There is absolutely no reason why judicious use of std or boost should be forbidden. With decent compiler (Visual C++ is not one of them), properly used boost or std code will produce just as efficient binary as manually written code while taking less time to debug (at the cost of taking longer to compile).

Comment: @Jan: if this is a homework assignment intended to teach basic principles (such as how iterators work and how templates can be specialised), then libraries certainly should be forbidden - using a ready-made solution won't teach you anything.

Comment: @Xeo: template<IterT> IterT Begin<IterT>() was a typo. Fixed

Comment: @Mike: Ok, when I see "HW", I understand "hardware", not "homework", but you are right – it probably meant the later.

Comment: @Mike. Haha. Sorry for being unclear. When you're a student HW is equivalent to homework by reflex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function templates cannot be specialized in C++, point.

It does not matter whether they are members of template or not, specialization of function templates is not allowed. Normally when using argument types to infer the template arguments, overloading does the same specialization would, so specialization for functions (and the associated extra complexity in overload resolution and such) was not deemed necessary.

You however don't have any arguments to infer on and would instantiate the templates manually. No,

```
DataStructure::DerivedIterator1 i = dataStructure.Begin();
```

would **not** work as you wrote the code, because type inference, just like overload resolution is only done on the arguments, not expected return value. You'd have to write:

```
DataStructure::DerivedIterator1 i = dataStructure.Begin<DataStructure::DerivedIterator1>();
```

and that has zero benefit over:

```
DataStructure::DerivedIterator1 i = dataStructure.BeginIterator1();
```

However, the first expression can be made to work with some wizardry. First you have to define `BeginIterator1` and `BeginIterator2` and than you'd do a temporary to late-decide which one to construct:

```
class DataStructure {
    ...
    class BeginIteratorConstructor {
        DataStructure &dataStructure;
    public:
        BeginIteratorConstructor(DataStructure &ds) : dataStructure(ds) {}
        operator DerivedIterator1() { return dataStructure.BeginIterator1(); }
        operator DerivedIterator2() { return dataStructure.BeginIterator2(); }
    };
    BeginIteratorConstructor Begin() { return BeginIteratorConstructor(*this); }
    ...
};
```

Now `dataStructure.Begin()` will return a temporary something, that will call `BeginIterator1` if you cast it to `DerivedIterator1` or call `BeginIterator2` when you cast it to `DerivedIterator2`. If you pass it to something where the compiler can't decide which one to cast to, it will die either because of ambiguous overload or because `BeginIteratorConstructor` is not in fact iterator and you'll have to cast it explicitly.

(You should carefully make as much of the `BeginIteratorConstructor` private, but I am not sure how far will the compiler allow you to go, so you'd have to experiment a bit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tagging system, which will save you from partially specialized functions inside class templates:

```
struct base_iter_tag{};
struct der1_iter_tag{};
struct der2_iter_tag{};

template<class T>
struct iter_type;

template<>
struct iter_type<BaseIterator>{
  typedef base_iter_tag tag;
};

template<>
struct iter_type<DerivedIterator1>{
  typedef der1_iter_tag tag;
};

template<>
struct iter_type<DerivedIterator2>{
  typedef der2_iter_tag tag;
};

template<class IterT>
IterT Begin(){
  return DoBegin(typename iter_type<IterT>::tag());
}

BaseIterator DoBegin(base_iter_tag){
  // ...
}

DerivedIterator1 DoBegin(der1_iter_tag){
  // ...
}

DerivedIterator2 DoBegin(der2_iter_tag){
  // ...
}
```

This is essentially what the standard library does with the `iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` and overloaded functions depending on the category (e.g. `forward_iterator_tag`, `random_access_iterator_tag`, etc...).